# iTextPDF.PdfReader returns only line breaks (\n), but content exists

Tags: java, itextpdf

I trying get content with PDF, but I get only linebreaks (\n)

In debugger, variable str = "\n    \n\n\n           \n   \n  " and more this characters.

```
       try {
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("C:\Users\lll\Desktop\65297.pdf");
            int n = reader.getNumberOfPages(); // prints 2 
            String str= PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader, 1);
            System.out.println(str);
            reader.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
```

If I open this file, content exists at 2 pages.

I don't know, what I may do in this problem.

Comment: Have you tried this with another pdf? Perhaps the text in the pdf you're trying isn't parseable.

Comment: Also tell us which version of iText you are using. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wxGEEv7ibHE) explains why not every PDF can be parsed. Did you take a look inside the PDF using [iText RUPS](http://itextpdf.com/product/itext_rups)?

Comment: Could this problem be related to the font used in the PDF?

Comment: @LLL as you can read in the other comments, certain pdfs ml can not be parsed for text successfully. If you shared your test PDF, we may check it.

Comment: unfortunately, this PDF is Invoice - I can't share. I use version 5.4.5.

Comment: the opening manually as this pdf and tries to copy the text and paste it into notepad is one character becomes such a characteristic square